Two-piece (break-apart) mechanical pencils
I once had a two-piece (aka break-apart) mechanical pencil. The two halves just slotted together when needed. It then functioned exactly like a normal mechanical pencil: ordinary (0.5mm) retractible lead at the working end and probably an eraser at the other. One half did not fit inside the other, except where they joined.
Someone permanently borrowed it so I have no photo and don't remember any brand name.
I found it amazingly useful for easily carrying around inside a very small container during my outdoor activities. Standard one-piece (or whole) mechanical pencils will either break too easily or, more likely, will poke holes in whatever delicate pouch is containing it.
So, instead of this
o================>-
there are these two halves which join when needed
o=======     and    =========>-
I'd like the lead to be retractable, to reduce risk of puncture during transport.
And of course it should be in two easy-to-join parts -- not the many components that all pencils might have if one were to begin intricate pencil repairs -- so it can be carried in a much-shorter-than normal case.
If they still exist, what are they actually called and what are the brands?
I've searched for both "break-apart mechanical pencil" and "two-piece mechanical pencil" but the former just points me to articles on repairs and the latter just points me to two-pencil sets.
(I'm not interested in prices -- no "price shopping".)

Do you need thick or thin leads? I have an old mechanical pencil lying around that has a full aluminium body, so no breaking anytime soon. But it only takes thick leads. I think there are also full metal mechanical pencils for thin leads, but probably for a much higher price than simple plastic ones and they'll probably poke through fabric even with the lead retracted.

Could the half with the lead be put inside the other half in reverse, to protect it? What was the actual function of it being able to be taken apart? It wasn't some kind of chatelaine pencil?

Seconding the request for information on the function of the pencil; a few searches across a web shop I frequent that offers an extremely wide variety of stationery supplies shows even "mini (mechanical) pencils" are standard length, due to the length of the leads.

I added various details, hoping they answer your questions.

This is the closest I found.
Penco Bullet Pencil Light


Despite being small in size (closed it measures 9.3 cm), when you uncover it and fit its lid on the back, you will gain a few centimeters (up to 13 cm) that will make this mechanical pencil fit perfectly in your hand.


penco.jp

Personally, I have never seen a pencil with the characteristics described. It makes me think that it is something very technical, like a carpenter's mechanical pencil.

Different frame challenge: instead of using one pencil that can be split into 2 parts, just use a very short pencil.
By searching for "mechanical pencil extra short" I found several options in the 10 - 11 cm (4 - 4 1/4  inch) range. There are also compasses with integrated mechanical pencils, like this example:

The pencil alone looks like it could be 8 - 9 cm long, but in this specific example it's not removable from the compass.
There's also a japanese product called "Raymay Pen Pass" with a removable mechanical pencil:

And I found a compass set "STAEDTLER CIRCOFIX" with several of these mini pencils. I think the general search term is "compass insert".
I also found this reddit post with a very short pencil, but I have no idea what's going on there, whether this is a genuine product that I couldn't find or this is a broken pencil.

The OP doesn't want a short pencil, they want a normal pencil that can be made short between uses.

@rebusB Rotring also make short mechanical pencils for their compasses (or did - mine is 30+ years old). And they make pens to fit in the same way. I think there might be a combination for the OP in that

@rebusB -- Not an exact answer to my exact question but it is an honest attempt to solve my problem. That STAEDTLER CIRCOFIX could have been a contender...

I will try to help you in a "funny" way. I read on the internet once that the Americans spent millions of dollars on researching a pen that could be used for writing in outer space (it seems that regular pens do not work). However, the Russians solved the problem for free, by using a pencil.
So I kind of go in the same direction: why use a complicated solution with a mechanical pencil (other than the "cool!" factor), when you can take a standard pencil, cut it in two or three pieces, sharpen them, use them. Or do not sharpen them, just carry a  pencil sharpener - it would protect the lead. Carry more pencils at once. Give them to your friends too, if needed.
This solution is actually implemented by hardware stores, where people need to be able to take notes or make small diagrams, and need the pencils for that. And providing full size pencils there would be overkill.
Note: To be on your side... If you ever remember or accidentally find what mechanical pencil you had, please share, I am curious. I am a kind of fan of writing instruments, even though I do not have a collection of them.

But the question isn't "what can I use instead?", it's "what is this particular tool called?", hence the [terminology] tag.

@Joachim: True. However, OP also mentioned "easily carrying around inside a very small container" and "Standard one-piece (or whole) mechanical pencils will either break too easily or, more likely, will poke holes in whatever delicate pouch is containing it."- and that is the part on which I focused. See? Not only that he wants some information, he also has a practical need. Maybe the question should be two questions, or two distinct sub-questions. And "I'd like the lead to be retractable" definitely hints at finding alternatives - according to my understanding. Tnx for no downvote:)

Drawing with a short pencil is a PIA, so I would say even if this addresses the storage aspect for the OP it does not provide a practical answer.

There's a time and a place for a stubby pencil - I carry them fairly often, but for writing brief notes. You used to be able to get pencil holders allowing very short stubs to be used - but they were fairly long themselves so might not be the answer.

@Joachim - Not an exact answer to my exact question but it is an honest attempt to solve my problem. I may yet resort to a simple short wood pencil + extender...
